# Read pdf table like structure(not exact table) in python and extract it to any file format

Tags: python, pdf, reader

I have a pdf file in which pages in the middle are filled with measurements. I Looks like a table but not completely alligned with lines. i want to extract the data in the same way as it Looks into a csv or Excel file.

Pdf file data sample:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
1       0.05    2.01    3.09   
2       5.05    4.01    6.03
3       7.01    8.02    1.00
```

There is no alignment in the pdf data. Like it is not seperated usign lines as like in  the table. So which module would be apt to use it to Export it as Excel or csv?

Comment: Use PyPDF2, here is the link, https://realpython.com/pdf-python/. Print out the content and then see how can you further process it. If you get stuck, post a question

Comment: How does this online tool handle your file (choose save as HTML to see the extraction)?: https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-tools/pdf-table-extraction/

Comment: I found a module https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula which is very useful and solves the purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can use textract to achieve this, but it also depends on file.

1. http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
2. https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract

It supports many types of files including PDFs

```
import textract
text = textract.process("path/to/file.pdf")
```

Comment: i can extract with many libraries. But the pdf data format is slightly unlikely it doesnot have text like paragraphs or table like lines sperated. So if i extract it doesnt appear to be in form of a table